# replaceAll to replace everything which doesn't match the provided regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

The method `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` from string class replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement. Is it possible to negate the regex so that everything which doesn't matches is replaced?

For example I've a string with a substring inside square brackets (No nested brackets and rest of string doesn't contain neither opening nor closing square brackets)

```
String test = "some text [keep this] may be some more ..";
```

I've found a regex to extract the substring between []:

```
String test = "some text [keep this] may be some more ..";        
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

while(m.find()) {
    test = m.group(1);
}
```

What I want to do is, if possible, to use the `replaceAll` method with somehow negated regex to replace everything which doesn't match the above regex.

```
String regex = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
test.replaceAll("(?!" + regex + "$).*", "")
```

This and some others, which i found by searching for "negate regex" didn't work for me.

Expected output is `test = "keep this"`

Comment: functionally speaking, could you not just `if(test.Contains("keep this") { test = "keep this";}`?  Not sure you need a regex for the example problem.

Comment: @Gus the text between [] can vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close you can use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) like so, with group like so ;

```
test = test.replaceAll(".*\\[(.*?)\\].*", "$1");
```

Comment: Shortest sequence in all trhee cases `.*?` is it not, except for ^ and $.

Comment: This does not work if there is more than one instance of "[keep this]" in the input. @JoopEggen has the better answer.

Comment: @blackpanda Yes I agree but It seems that the OP have only one else his/her code works very fine check the [ideon demo](http://www.ideone.com/hytcNo) all I add it is a println

Answer (score 3):

A bit more circumstantial, but why not loop over the pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Java >= 9
m.replaceAll(mr -> sb.append(mr.group(1)));

// Java <= 8
while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(m.group(1));
}

String result = sb.toString();
```